# How to mutate a new variable that summarizes X number of previous rows based on an if_else statement?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, dplyr

I have a spatial data frame with GPS points every second as well as the distance traveled between points and turning angles. I'd like to create a new column that summarises the amount of time it took to travel 10m and the average turning angle over the last 10 meters.

| row | x | y | date | dx | dy | dist | dt | R2n | abs.angle | rel.angle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 580988. | 12981141. | 2021-07-18 07:00:07 | -1.99 | -0.0128 | 1.99 | 1 | 0 | -3.14 | NA |
| 2 | 580986. | 12981141. | 2021-07-18 07:00:08 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3.94 | NA | NA |
| 3 | 580986. | 12981141. | 2021-07-18 07:00:09 | 2.97 | 1.13 | 3.18 | 1 | 3.94 | 0.363 | -2.79 |
| 4 | 580989. | 12981142. | 2021-07-18 07:00:10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2.21 | NA | NA |

In other words, I'd like a column "sum.dist" that should always be close to 10 and then two more columns "sum.dt" and average.rel.angle that summarize the time it took the subject to move the previous 10 meters and the average rel.angle over those last 10 meters. I'm aware I'm probably going to need some kind of loop to check to see when the sum of distances is approximately 10 (say the first value to be greater than 10 meters?) and then count the number of rows and use that number of rows to summarize over row n and rows n-x. Unfortunately, I'm having a really hard time even figuring out how to start here. I'm comfortable with basic dplyr functions like mutate and summarise but I am inexperienced with loops.

Comment: I think something like `slider::slide_index(rel.angle, dist, mean, .before = 10)` should give you the average rel.angle in a rolling window of (up to) 10 meters distance traveled. Can you please share an example of your data by including the output of `dput(head(YOUR_TABLE, 10))` in your question? That will be easier for potential answerers to use since it will let us recreate the data directly without making guesses about data types.

Comment: Thank you! This package looks like just the kind of thing I needed. I haven't used dput before and my RStudio console tried to print a massive amount of data when I ran that line of code with the full table (the first 4 rows are copied in my original post) which is thousands of rows of spatial data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one (kinda clunky) way of doing this. I am not sure how you want to group your data by distance. Here, I assumed the first row was 0 and grouped data 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, etc. Is this what you were expecting?

```
library(dplyr)

# Calculate distance between consecutive rows
df$dist <- c(0, sqrt(diff(df$x)^2 + diff(df$y)^2))
# Calculate a rolling distance
df$roll <- cumsum(df$dist)
# Group rows by every 10 meters
df$grp <- factor(floor(df$roll/10) * 10)
# Calculate summary values by group
summ <- df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarize(
    sum.dt = sum(dt),
    average.rel.angle = mean(rel.angle, na.rm = TRUE))
# Combine summary with original data
merge(df, summ, by="grp")
```

Data:

```
structure(list(row = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), x = c(580985, 
580990, 580995, 581000, 581005, 581010, 581015), y = c(12981141, 
12981141, 12981141, 12981141, 12981141, 12981141, 12981141), 
    date = structure(list(sec = c(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), min = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L), mday = c(18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), mon = c(6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), year = c(121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 
    121L, 121L, 121L), wday = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
        yday = c(198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L), isdst = c(1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), zone = c("EDT", "EDT", "EDT", 
        "EDT", "EDT", "EDT", "EDT"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
        NA_integer_)), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), dx = c(-1.99, 
    0, 2.97, 0, 0, 0, 0), dy = c(-0.0128, 0, 1.13, 0, 0, 0, 0
    ), dist = c(1.99, 0, 3.18, 0, 0, 0, 0), dt = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), R2n = c(0, 3.94, 3.94, 2.21, 2.21, 2.21, 2.21), 
    abs.angle = c(-3.14, NA, 0.363, NA, NA, NA, NA), rel.angle = c(NA, 
    NA, -2.79, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c("a", "b", "d", 
"e", "f", "g", "h"), class = "data.frame")
```